# creating a variable names out of character vector

Tags: r, dplyr

There are occasions where a vector with column names of data frame need to be passed into a function ( `dplyr mutate` in my case).

example column name vector is a as `c(V1, V2, V3, V4, V5, V6, V7, V8, V9, V10)`

I can construct this as a character vector as `paste0("V", 1:10)`.

```
> paste0("V", 1:10)
 [1] "V1"  "V2"  "V3"  "V4"  "V5"  "V6"  "V7"  "V8"  "V9"  "V10"
```

How do I transform this such that it can be passed to the median function below instead of writing down the unwieldy long column names in there ?

```
df %>%
rowwise() %>%
mutate(median_val = median(c(V1, V2, V3, V4, V5, V6, V7, V8, V9, V10), na.rm = T))
```

**Example data**

```
id  loc  V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6  V7  V8  V9 V10
1  loc1  80  80  80  80  64  64  80  80  80  80
2  loc2  64  64  64  64  64  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA 
3  loc2 256 256 256 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 
4  loc3  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
```

**Output Expected**

```
id  loc  median_val
1  loc1  80
2  loc2  64 
3  loc2 240
4  loc3  NA
```

Comment: Use `mutate_at`/`mutate_all` or if you must, `mutate_`.

Comment: I think OP wants the median *across* those variables, not for each.

Comment: @r2evans - that's correct - median across V1:V10

Comment: I think it may be more efficient to use `rowMedians` from `matrixTools` after converting the dataset to `matrix`

Comment: if that isn't an immediate solution for you, it would help to have a little more context with sample data; specifically, is the data.frame in question made up entirely of these `V` columns, or are there others? Is it realistic to break this data.frame up so that only the `V` columns (and a join-able key), run it as a matrix, then re-join back with the data?

Comment: @r2evans added sample data

Comment: what is the result you expect from your sample data?

Comment: @and added expected output

Answer (score 1):

```
df2 = data.frame(c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), c(1:5), c(6:10), c(1,1,1,NA,1), rep(NA,5))
colnames(df2) = paste0("v", 1:5)
apply(df2[,paste0("v", 2:5)], 1, median, na.rm = T)
```

Comment: is this what you looking for?